# How can I create a new series by calculating the values in my pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this:

```
like_count  dislike_count   dog_video   cat_video   bird_video  other_animal_video  animal_category
1000          500            True          False       False         False               dog
5500          300            False         True        False         False               cat
2300          100            False         False       True          False               bird
1100          200            False         False       False         True                other
```

What I need to do is to create a new series by calculating the number of dog, cat, bird and other in the **animal_category**. My new series should look like this:

```
animal_names number of animals  
dog                50
cat                20
bird               15
other              30
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `df['animal_category'].value_counts()`?

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (from @Quang Hoang's answer) is to use `groupby()`

```
output_df = df.groupby(['animal_category'],as_index=False)['like_count'].count().rename(columns={'like_count':'number of animals'})
```

Comment: Wow! This works also! But I could not understand why you used like count. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Wow! This works also! But I could not understand why you used like count. What is the reason for that? –

Comment: Sorry for taking sometime to answer. So first I'm grouping on the column `animal_category`, this will generate that each row is a unique `animal_category`. Next, what data do I want to show? Well I'd like to **count** how many rows belong to each `animal_category` and that is the reason for the `count`.

Comment: No worries Ivan. Thanks for your answer. But I was trying to ask why you used ['like_count']? Why do we have it in our code?

Comment: Oh, I just had to pick one column at random to perform the `count` operation on. I picked that one because it seems most consistent. Another way is to reset_index() and use it to perform the `count` on and later drop it (to make sure there are no NaN values).